# Mime Type for Podcasts?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

Is there a specific Mime type or URL prefix (itpc?) for podcasts? For computers that do not have iTunes installed (e.g., a Linux or Windows box without ITunes), is there an automatic way to open a Podcast from a browser, knowing just the URL of the podcast? Or must podcasts be viewed through a podcast listener (like iTunes) or a site (like Feedburner)?

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, if you view a feed (by going to its URI) any entries that are podcasts will have audio file attachments.

Comment: thanks for that, relevant and interesting. It probably responds to the declared DTD of the XML (or somethin').